# jQuery animate not moving to the correct location

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I've run into a mysterious problem.  I'm using jQuery's `animate` function and the object I'm animating is not moving to the 'left' coordinate I provide; rather the left coordinate is always 0.  However, the 'top' coordinate does move as expected.  I had this working fine at one point and I rearranged some things around and it has stopped.

```
        var new_x,
            new_y,
            player_tranistion_holder;

        new_x = bg_app.boardModel[id_num].x+'px';
        new_y = (bg_app.boardModel[id_num].chips.length) * bg_app.game_utils.parse_css_dimension(selected_chip.chip.css('height'));

        console.log(new_x) //outputs 300px for example - the expected value;

        selected_chip.chip.animate({'left':  new_x, 'top': new_y }, 500, 'easeInOutQuad', function () {
               console.log(selected_chip.chip.css('left'); //output is 0
        });
```

Any idea what could cause this to screw up?  The stuff I changed around it was merely in how the function came to be called, nothing in the function itself.  Do I have some syntax error that I'm missing?

I've put the broken site here:

http://www.warunicorn.com/bg_show_busted/

here is an example with it working:

http://www.warunicorn.com/bg_show/

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: ATM the site works best in firefox.  It will work in Chrome but for some reason the height property isn't getting parsed when the part of the code that sets up the layout is executed and all the boxes are stacked on top of one another.

Comment: It would help to know what's supposed to be happening... do I need to learn how to play your game in order to assist you?

Comment: ha! no.  It's hardly a game at this point... I thought the rules at the top and the working link would be enough, but you're right.  basically, you click the color you want to start with, then you click a block that has that chip, finally, you click on a block you want it to move to.  It should move to that block, not to 0

Comment: "chip"?  I don't see any chips.

Comment: yeah, well, use your imagination... the green and red boxes :)

Comment: My best suggestion would be to condense this down into a jsFiddle.  Otherwise, since you already have a working version, start over, make only one small change at a time until you break it again.

Comment: that's a good suggestion.  Any particular reason this question got voted down?

Comment: Of course, only the voter knows the answer to that question.

Comment: well, I didn't mean to be snarky there, if that is how it sounded.  Anyhow, your tried and true suggestion and it worked.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.  Please post your solution below and accept your own answer for the benefit of the community.

Comment: @JoeM05 is your answer anyway related your statemachine.onleavedecide_chip function returning false before the animation being completed? just curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  When using the animate function if the new value passed in is the same as the current value of the object jQuery gets confused and sets the value to 0.  I haven't done extensive testing on this and so there may be exceptions where it does work, but in this case, that was the problem.